# Trying to get data from multiple lines of a file and putting them into a struct

Tags: c++

the function only gets the first menu item and price and does not get the remaining item's data and prices. The file that I am gathering input from is formatted as such:

```
"menu item"
"price of menu item"
"menu item"
"price of menu item"
```

```
void getData(MenuItem menuList[], int &size)
{
    inFile.open();



    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(!inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile, menuList[i].description);
            inFile >> menuList[i].price;
            menuList[i].quantity = 0;
            size++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Delete `.eof()`.  Check all the failure conditions instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

Several errors here:

- The input file contains no "price" (or did it get lost when copying to StackOverflow?)
- You use "getline", which will read an *entire* line. You then use "operator >>" to read the price (which is missing from the input). "operator>>" does *not* read an entire line. It tries to extract exactly one value. Also it's value MUST NOT be in quotes. My guess is (haven't checked), eof is true after you unsuccessfully tried reading a price with `operator>>`.
- [A little confusing though, since I'd expect the **fail** bit to be
  set, not the **eof**. But perhaps `inFile.fail()` is set after the
  `operator>>` and then the next read operation will `eof`, since it
  tried to read from a `fail`].
- Don't (usually) mix `getline` and `operator>>`

Other suggestions:

- DON'T use old-style C-Vectors: `MenuItem menuItem[]` EVER. There is absolutely no reason to use them in 2021 anymore. (Unless you are a real pro and really, desperately need them ...)
- Use std::vector menuItem instead (no square brackets)
- Use menuItem.size() to get the number of elements in the list. Rewrite your for loop like this `for (int i=0; i<menuItem.size(); ++i)`. That way you will not get invalid memory access errors.
- Better still, rewrite your for loop like this: `for (auto &item:menuItem)` and use `item` instead of `menuItems[i]`;

Comment: also, never check for `eof()` before reading, check immediately after. Or rather, as you said, check for failure. Those flags are set as a result of operation which already produced uninitialized values. When end of file reached, `eof()\fail()` is set on next operation when we attempt to read past end of file. That's the danger of `getline()` - if file doesn't have end-of-line character before `eof()`, we would miss that last line - it's undefined if `getline()` would fetch partial string, and in real cases it would not.